# Sorting Table with checkbox: content is not visible anymore

Tags: javascript, checkbox, tabular

This is the the HTML of a table and the JS code that I'm trying. Basically clicking a checkbox another table will appears:

```
<form class="filter">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" class="unchecked"> EG
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1OG" class="unchecked"> 1.OG
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2OG" class="unchecked"> 2.OG
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3OG" class="unchecked"> 3.OG
</form>

<script>

 $('input.unchecked').on('change', function() {
 $('input.unchecked').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});

</script>


<script>

$("#checkboxID").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.rowEG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

    $("#checkbox1OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row1OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

    $("#checkbox2OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row2OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

    $("#checkbox3OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row3OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

</script>
```

But on click the table disappears.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look to the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). I specially reccomend to see the section [How to make a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens if you have a checkbox selected and then you select another one without deselecting manually the previous one. Otherwise it works well.

I suggest you to define a function like this:

```
function restore_table() {
    $("#tableID tr.rowEG").toggle(true);
    $("#tableID tr.row1OG").toggle(true);
    $("#tableID tr.row2OG").toggle(true);
    $("#tableID tr.row3OG").toggle(true);
}
```

Then you can call this function on each individual `change()` call before operating the table rows. For example:

```
// Do this with the four change calls
$("#checkboxEG").change(function(){
    restore_table();
    $("#tableID tr.rowEG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});
```

Comment: @A.Developer Please forgive the rushing with copy-paste from mobile. I have corrected the mistake I made in my example function, and provided somemore example. Please check it out.

Comment: I edited the first post with your code, but does not works. Or i did it wrong?

Comment: @A.Developer This time I had my computer at hand, and could test from it. My code was wrong. I have edited the answer. Now it will work. I have tested it this time. In the custom function I made, just replace `false` by `true`

Comment: Hi :) this works great with 1OG, 2OG and 3OG but not with the EG checkbox. How come?

Comment: @A.Developer In the question you had a [typo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error) in `$("#checkboxID").change`, it should be `$("#checkboxEG")`. If this typo is also in your website's source code, that is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Each checkbox filter rows with a specific class, it means when you check first chckbox and then click another one, the second checkbox cant find rows with the class which it is searching for, i mean, when you check a checkbox and then check another checkbox, the .on(change) method,only manage checkboxs check, and not remove filtering...

```
$('input.unchecked').on('change', function() {
 $('input.unchecked').not(this).prop('checked', false);  

});
```

you should reset filtered rows before doing any new filtering...

```
function restRows(){
$('#tableID tr').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
}).show();
}
```

and call it before any filtering like this :

```
    $("#checkbox3OG").change(function(){

    //reset all hidden rows
    restRows();

    //filter new rows
    $("#tableID tr.row3OG").hide();
});
```